# multiplying brackets containing vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, self-learning

I am reading [this](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/machine-learning-0) book and came across a transformation that I did not understand:

$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}}) (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^{T} = \frac{1}{N} (\sum_{i=1}^{N} \mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T})-\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}$

where $\mathbf{x}_{i}$ and $\mathbf{\bar{x}}$ are both vectors.

When I expand the brackets I get something like this:

$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}}) (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^{T} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}-\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}-\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}+\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}$

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}}) (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^{T} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}-\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}-\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}+\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $   \mathbf{\bar{x}}= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \mathbf{x}_{i} $
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}}) (\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})^{T} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T})-\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}-\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}+\mathbf{\bar{x}}\mathbf{\bar{x}}^{T}
\end{eqnarray*}
so the terms cancel out and you will obtain the desired result.